# Sub will not execute in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have an simple problem (I think), but I'm stuck

I'm calling a sub from another sub but it is not working. I mean, the 2nd sub is not being executed.

```
Private Sub start()
...
FormatSheets 1
End Sub


Public Sub FormatSheets(planMonthNum As Integer)
...
End Sub
```

There is no error code. When debugging with F8 it goes over the line but it doesn't jump to execute the other sub.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by " it is not working"? Does it throw any error? Try to step thrugh `start` by pressing F8.

Comment: Did you use the debugger yet and traced whether the line "FormatSheets 1" is even executed in the start() sub? Any error messages?

Comment: Based on this piece of code we aren't even able to check what's wrong with your code...

Comment: Sorry, I've added additional comments. I did debug the code, but when it gets to the line to execute the sub it doesn't do it. It just goes to the next line

Comment: Do you have any `On Error ...` line somewhere above the call to FormatSheets ?

Comment: No I don't have 'on error' in the code. The think is that the debugging goes through the line

Comment: Vincent G, you game the clue. I found the problem, there was a 'Unload Me' command. commenting this it worked. I'll post the solution

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by this line this command 'Unload Me'

```
Private Sub start()
...
Unload Me
....
FormatSheets 1
End Sub


Public Sub FormatSheets(planMonthNum As Integer)
...
End Sub
```

Commenting 'Unload Me' resolved the problem

Hope it helps someone else